# Нет прав на открытие файла, но права установлены (Linux Mint)

Tags: linux, unix

В Linux mint смонтирован диск NTFS. 
Опции монтирования `uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=077,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=Disk%20D`

На диске есть такая папка `/mnt/diskD/webserver/htdocs/website/files/css`

- Permissions: `-rwx------` файлы, `-drwx------` папки
- Owner: me

При попытке открыть файл (например animations.css) тем не менее выдает ошибку

> Could not open the file /mnt/diskD/webserver/htd…ite/files/css/animate.css. You do not have the permissions necessary to open the file.

`sudo nano animations.css` - та же ошибка `Access denied`

Причем странное поведение в разных папках на разных уровнях:

- `/mnt/diskD/webserver/htd…ite/files/` файлы открываются.
- `/mnt/diskD/webserver/htd…ite/files/node_modules` файлы открываются.
- `/mnt/diskD/webserver/htd…ite/files/js` файлы  **НЕ** открываются.
- `/mnt/diskD/webserver/htd…ite/files/css` файлы  **НЕ** открываются.

Скриншоты:
[image: Ошибка открытия js]
[image: Ошибка открытия css]

Команда `ls -l` для

```
dimas@linux:/mnt/diskD/webserver/htdocs/website/files/css$ ls -l
```

выдает
`-rwxr-x--- 1 dimas dimas 62525 Mar 6 2018 animate.css`

Для уровня выше

```
dimas@linux:/mnt/diskD/webserver/htdocs/website/files$ ls -l

drwxr-x--- 1 dimas dimas     0 Mar 18  2018 ajax
drwxr-x--- 1 dimas dimas  4096 Oct 25 22:37 css
-rwxr-x--- 1 dimas dimas   479 Aug  6 22:06 package.json
-rwxr-x--- 1 dimas dimas  9583 Aug  6 22:06 package-lock.json
-rwxr-x--- 1 dimas dimas  3333 Mar 20  2018 send_form_email.php
```

Перепробовал кучу вариантов монтирования и установки прав. Права есть. В чем проблема не понимаю. Прошу помочь советом.

**UPD: скриншот конкретно для папки /css**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Важно:** файлы в смежных папках проекта или в других проектах на диске доступны полностью. Читаю, записываю. Только конкретно в этом проекте с этими двумя папками /css и /js. В них файлы могу только переименовать и удалить. Прочитать не могу.

Comment: Что показывает `ls -l`?

Comment: `dimas@linux:/mnt/diskD/webserver/htdocs/website/files/css$ ls -l
total 684

-rwxr-x--- 1 dimas dimas  62525 Mar  6  2018 animate.css
`

Comment: а каталог/файлы случаем не сжатые или не зашифрованные? затрудняюсь сказать, как посмотреть это в linux... ЗЫ: `nano` или `cat` от обычного пользователя также не работает?

Answer (score 0):

А у Вас драйвер ntfs-3g установлен?

У меня в файле *fstab* монтирование виндовозных дисков прописано так:

```
# Диски Windows                                                                                                 
/dev/sda2 /mnt/disk_c ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.utf8 0 0                                                    
/dev/sda3 /mnt/disk_d ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.utf8 0 0
```

И всё работает без проблем.

Comment: Привет, спасибо за совет, да драйвер стоит. Диск смонтирован нормально. Пробовал и ваши настройки. Не работает. Проблема та же. На диске имею  доступ ко всем своим файлам и папкам. Только конкретно с этим проектом беда. Ну вот могу эти файлы в папке .css переименовывать, удалять и тп. Права есть, проверял и через `sudo ls -ail`
В соседних папках проекта все открывается без проблем. Только беда с этими двумя. Просто голову сломал уже.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос скриншот терминала
команды `sudo ls -ail`, `sudo nano animate.css` и `whoami`

Answer (score 0):

В `umask=077` пропустили? нолик, надо? : `umask=0077`

Скорее всего ещё нужно добавить `,dmask=0077,fmask=0077` - попробуйте.

...

Единственное, что знаю это в ntfs эти папки могут быть зашифрованы. Открываются только в винде у конкретного пользователя, кто зашифровал. Нужно в винде под этим пользователем отключить шифрование этих папок. У меня дома есть такая папка:

```
alex423@linux-8zsb:/ntfs/Users/Alex/секрет> sudo cat новый\ пароль 
[sudo] пароль для root: 
cat: 'новый пароль': Отказано в доступе
```

Comment: Привет, спасибо. Пробовал тоже. По всякому уже пробовал. Права как бы есть. Смонтирован диск нормально, есть доступ к разным проектам, даже смежным папкам и файлам конкретно этого проекта. Только беда с  файлами папок /css и /js. Ни в какую не хотят открываться. Нет прав и все. Хотя права есть.

Comment: отключите шифрование в винде. см . ответ